# I cant load Ruby Gems

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm

i am getting this error whenever i try to load a ruby gem

```
/home/hilarl/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- twit
ter (LoadError)
        from /home/hilarl/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from sample.rb:2:in `<main>'
```

can you please help?

Comment: have you installed the gem in question with `gem install twitter`?

Comment: Yes the gem is installed

Comment: OK.  so what does `gem which twitter` report?

Comment: this is what i get from gem which twitter 'ERROR:  Can't find ruby library file or shared library twitter'

Comment: So the twitter gem is not installed.  Run `gem install twitter`.  No sudo; you're installing into your RVM instance of Ruby.  Pay attention to the output to make sure it succeeds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed to use a ruby, in normal console first run:

```
rvm use 1.9.3
```

If it's in a script then instead use following path to ruby:

```
$rvm_path/wrappers/ruby-1.9.3-p194/ruby
```

You should get also the minimal basics of using RVM:

- screencast: http://screencasts.org/episodes/how-to-use-rvm
- cheatsheet: http://cheat.errtheblog.com/s/rvm/
- rvm site: https://rvm.io/

Comment: I don't know, it looks like the script in question is successfully being run by the rvm-installed Ruby. I was trying to ascertain if maybe the twitter gem were installed in the system Ruby instead..