# `require': cannot load such file -- mail (LoadError)

Tags: ruby, ide, editor, rvm, geany

In trying to use the mail gem from [geany](http://www.geany.org/) I get errors as so:

```
/home/thufir/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- mail (LoadError)
    from /home/thufir/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from mail.rb:3:in `<main>'


------------------
(program exited with code: 1)
Press return to continue
```

However, the program runs fine from the CLI:

```
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ ruby ruby/mail.rb 
hello world
hello world
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ nl ruby/mail.rb 
     1  require 'yaml'
     2  require 'net/imap'
     3  require 'mail'

     4  2.times do
     5    puts 'hello world'
     6  end
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p327 (2012-11-10 revision 37606) [i686-linux]
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ gem -v
1.8.24
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ rvm -v

rvm 1.17.2 (stable) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]

thufir@dur:~$
```

Why does geany have trouble with the mail gem?

Just to confirm:

```
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ type rvm | head -1
rvm is a function
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ gem list --local

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bundler (1.2.3)
i18n (0.6.1)
mail (2.5.3)
mime-types (1.19)
polyglot (0.3.3)
rake (10.0.3)
rubygems-bundler (1.1.0)
rvm (1.11.3.5)
treetop (1.4.12)
thufir@dur:~$
```

[geany mailing list question](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.editors.geany.general/7201/focus=7205)

[related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10679196/i-cant-load-ruby-gems?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your system is not configured to use login shell, here is an example how to enable login shell in gnome terminal https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal/

also running:

```
rvm get head --auto-dotfiles
```

will update your shell configuration to load rvm in the "right" way

Comment: interesting, I'll try that tonight.  That command will obviate the need to set the 'Run command as login shell' checkbox on the Title and Command tab inside of gnome-terminal's Settings page?

Comment: setting that checkbox is still required, we did not find way yet to set it automatically

Comment: provided that geany is run from the shell, and not started by clicking "geany" with the mouse, it works fine.  see:  http://article.gmane.org/gmane.editors.geany.general/7206